# Fetch mails from gmail account using php IMAP

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I was using the php imap function to connect and get the emails from the Gmail account and it was working fine but now, due to their updated policy i am getting the following error even though the login credentials are correct

```
PHP Warning:  imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}[Gmail]/All Mail in 

PHP Notice:  Unknown: Retrying PLAIN authentication after [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
```

I think it is because they are updated the policy. Is there any way to make this work?

These are the current code to connect to the account

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}[Gmail]/All Mail';
$imap = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password);
$emails = imap_search($imap, 'ALL');
if($emails) echo count($emails);
```

Comment: Have you set an App Password in Gmail?

Comment: no, i haven't created the app password

Comment: This was introduced about a year ago I think. Applications which can't use 2FA need to sign in with an App Password, not the default account password. More info at https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?sjid=6399608693125087466-EU and elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I created the app password and now able to login from the application and see the emails. :)

Comment: This may help in the future[How to create an apps password](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/IGOt3zo98Xw)

Answer (score 1):

Applications which can't use 2-factor authentication need to sign in to Gmail with an App Password, not the default account password.

More info on setting up a App Password within your Gmail account is available at https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?sjid=6399608693125087466-EU and elsewhere.